# More efficient way to list prime numbers in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, primes

I am not sure how to list primes in an arry within one function. Since may code is split into two functions my guess is that this has a significant impact on performance. 
How can I make the code below me more efficient?

```
function prime_check(n)
    
    primes = []
    trash  = []
    
    for i in 2:n-1
        if n%i == 0
            push!(trash, 1)
        end 
    end
    
    if length(trash) == 0
        push!(primes, n)
    end

    return primes
       
end

function prime_list(n)
    
    list = []
    
    for i in 2:n
        
        if length(prime_check(i)) > 0          
            push!(list, prime_check(i)[1])
        end
            
    end
    return list
end
```

Comment: Why not use `Prime.jl`?

Comment: Starting with a list of the primes up to 13 and only iterating over odd numbers would gain a lot. But as the code is creating a list of primes, why not try dividing by them instead of all numbers? Also, once you've found that n%i == 0 there is no need to try any more numbers, so `trash` is not needed.

Comment: start with not using `Any[]` like `primes = []`

Comment: Just a few comments. 1) Yes, there is room for optimization, other comments have touched on a few aspects. 2) No, writing your algorithm in multiple methods is not inherently slower than writing it all in one method. 3) Designing an efficient primality test algorithm is VERY difficult, and for large integers, the algorithm will matter way more than any optimizations you could allow Julia's compiler to do. I suggest you research the existing primality test algorithms and code your favorite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using some package to optimize your code, I recommend using "[Primes.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/Primes.jl/stable/)".

To install it, run:

```
Pkg.add("Primes")
```

from the Julia REPL.

This package has some functions built for factorization, identification of prime numbers, prime number generator, etc.

**Primes.isprime — Function.**

```
isprime(n::Integer) -> Bool
```

Example:

```
julia> isprime(3)
true
```

I hope I was helpfull.